# How do I create... endless amount of pages/routes?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a notes app. I want the user to be able to create a note and then within that note they can create a sub category/folder. So folders within folders... Is that possible?

I'm new...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. This can be done in a millon different ways. Start with some form of data model:

```
class Folder {
  final String name;
  List<Folder>? folders;
  Folder(this.name);
}

class Note {
  List<Folder>? folders;
}
```

Then you have to choose how you want to present that. For instance have a page that you push to the stack that takes a Folder object as an argument.

```
class FolderViewer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Folder folder;
  const FolderViewer({Key? key, required this.folder}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(folder.name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That helps!

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are doing but I set up a messaging app where each group of messages has card you can tap on (think a folder in your case) and then in each group there are parent messages that have children as the replies. The parent messages would be like your folder in a folder.

I did this by assigning IDs through firebase. So your top level folder would be a collection of either notes or folders inside of them. You'd have the top level ID and set the parentID of that to anything inside ofthat folder. If it is another folder inside of that folder you can set the parentID of whatever is in the second folder to the second folder.

Probably not exactly the answer you're looking for but I feel like adding relational IDs inside of firebase could do the trick for oyu.